# Where in my code do I use $_GET['token']?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP, and I have been working on setting up a reset password script. The biggest problem I am having is storing the last part of the URL into the variable $token.

What exactly do I need to have to ensure that the $token variable gets set after the user clicks the 'Reset Password' button? As of now, after the button is clicked, $token is not set to anything and the url turns into "www.website.com/resetpassword.php" without the token at the end. Thanks for your help!

Here is my form code:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
    <div class="login_form">
        <h2 style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 28pt; padding-top: 50px;">Forgot Password</h2>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" maxlength="60"/>
        <?php
        if ( isset($sucMSG) ) {
            echo '<span class="successful_registration">'.$sucMSG.'</span>';
        }

        if ( isset($matchError) ) {
            echo '<span class="text-danger">'.$matchError.'</span>';
        }

        if ( isset($keyError) ) {
            echo '<span class="text-danger">'.$keyError.'</span>';
        }
        ?>

        <br>
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="New Password" maxlength="255" />

        <br>
        <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" maxlength="255" />

        <input type="hidden" name="token" value= "random" />
        <br>

        <button type="submit" name="btn-reset">Reset Password</button>
        <br><br><br>
        <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
if (isset($_POST['btn-reset'])){
    // Gather the post data
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $email = strip_tags($email);

    $pass = trim($_POST['pass']);
    $pass = strip_tags($pass);

    $cpass = trim($_POST['cpass']);
    $cpass = strip_tags($cpass);

    $token = $_GET ['token'];

    // Retrieve token from database
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT token FROM token WHERE userEmail=? and NOW() < expire_date');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $resetKey = $row['token'];
    }

    // Does the new reset key match the old one?
    if ($resetKey == $token && isset($token)){
        if ($pass == $cpass){
            //hash and secure the password
            $password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

            // Update the user's password
            $stmt = $conn->prepare('UPDATE user SET userPass = ? WHERE userEmail = ?');
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $password);
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $conn = null;
            $sucMSG = "Your password has been successfully reset.";
            unset($email);
            unset($pass);
            unset($cpass);
            unset($token);
            unset($resetKey);
        }
        else
            $matchError = "Your password's do not match.";
    }
    else
        $keyError = "Your password reset key is invalid.";
}
```

Here is the PHP code from the previous step (forgotpassword.php):

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])){
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $email = strip_tags($email);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($email);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE userEmail = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    // If the count is equal to one, we will send message other wise display an error message.
    if($count==1){
        $rows=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $length = 55;
        $token  =  bin2hex(random_bytes($length));//Creating Token
        $create_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("now"));
        $expire_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime("+3 hours"));
        //Using prepared statements to prevent SQL Injection
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO token (token, userEmail, create_date, expire_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)');
        $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $token, $email, $create_date, $expire_date);
        $stmt->execute();

        // Create a url which we will direct them to reset their password
        $pwrurl = 'https://www.domain.com/resetpassword.php?token='.$token;     

        $to = $rows['userEmail'];
        //Details for sending E-mail
        $from = "Company";
        $body  =  "Company password recovery<br>
        -----------------------------------------------<br><br>
        Welcome to Company password recovery.
        You can reset your password by clicking the following link: $pwrurl.<br><br>
        Sincerely,<br><br>
        Company";
        $from = "support@company.com";
        $subject = "Company Password recovered";
        $headers1 = "From: $from\n";
        $headers1 .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers1 .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";
        $headers1 .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\r\n";
        $headers1 .= "X-Mailer: Just My Server\r\n";
        $sentmail = mail ( $to, $subject, $body, $headers1 );
    }
    elseif ($_POST['email'] == ""){
        $fMSG = "Please enter an email address.";
    } /*else {
    if ($_POST['email'] != "") 
    $wMSG = "Cannot send password to your email address. Problem with sending mail.";
    }*/
    //If the message is sent successfully, display sucess message otherwise display an error message.
    if($sentmail==1){
        $sMSG = "Your Password Has Been Sent To Your Email Address.";
    }
    else{
        if($_POST['email']!="")
            $nMSG = "Cannot send password to your email address. Problem with sending mail.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Code please? Did you set the proper attributes as the form?

Comment: I edited my post and added my code.

Comment: Your code is already using the variable. Your problem lays in the previous step, the generation of the token. You would need to send the full link e.g; `http://www.example.com/resetpassword.php?token=$generated_token` to the inbox of the person who requested the reset in order to make this a working script

Comment: Also, you cannot use `$_POST` and `$_GET` at the same time; in particular, your form is set to post data which means that the url is not changed by submitting the form.

Comment: I have added the code used for the previous step that sends an email with the token attached like your example.

Comment: @Isaiah - that's not really true.. you can use `post` and `get` at the same time.

Comment: ask Barmar; he gave an answer. Personally, I think the problem's elsewhere.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the way you're appending `$token` to the URL. Is it inserting the token into the database correctly? BTW, you shouldn't use `htmlspecialchars()` when inserting into the database. That's for escaping characters that you echo onto a web page, you shouldn't use it for anything else.

Comment: Is there a popular tutorial that says to use `trim+strip_tags+htmlspecialchars` on user input? I saw the exact same pattern in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40346824/why-i-cant-check-my-input-and-register-my-data-into-database earlier today.

Comment: in this line `$pwrurl = 'https://www.domain.com/resetpassword.php?token='.$token;`, you are only generating the url, but you also have to makeit a hyperlink like this: `$pwrurl = '<a href="https://www.domain.com/resetpassword.php?token='.$token.'" target="_blank">here</a>';`

Comment: Thanks for the comments! One problem I found out was with`$length = 55;
        $token  =  bin2hex(random_bytes($length));`. I didn't realize the bin2hex doubled the number of characters so my database was only storing the token per the limit of 55. When I add `echo $token;` into my PHP script, it does not appear on the screen. I still can't get $token to stay set after the reset password button is pressed.

Comment: Why don't you use the token as a hidden field rather than in query string, just a suggestion.

Comment: @jh95 which was my original thought about the length. Since the length for it most probably surpasses the column's length, you need to increase it by ALTERing the column to be of a higher value in length, one big enough. You then need to clear the values from it and start over; you have no choice. I believe this to be the answer/solution to the question. If you know how to ping someone directly, do. If not, use the @ symbol followed by the member's name (such as I) to contact them directly. Let me know if you wish for me to post my comment as an answer in order to mark the question as solved.

Comment: @HSharma suggestion was what ultimately solved my problem. I added this to my html form `<?php echo'
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="';
    if (isset($_GET['token'])) {
     echo $_GET['token'];
    }
     echo '" />'
    
   ?>` and in my PHP script I added `$token = $_POST ['token'];` and now the token sets properly. Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't know how to ping people, but the comment above this one has what ended up solving my problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: My pleasure @jh95 got your message :)

Comment: @HSharma wait, I have to alter my answer. I will convert to a community wiki to include comments. Darn it *lol*

Comment: @HSharma sorry about the ping (earlier); I meant to ping the OP and didn't have time to edit it. I included (your) comment(s) in a community wiki since I believe that both of ours was a mix of issues here, if that column wasn't long enough to hold the data to start with.

Comment: *"I don't know how to ping people"* @jh95 you just did ;-)

Comment: :) gets confusing sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: I am posting as a community wiki, since no rep gain should come of this.

> *"Why don't you use the token as a hidden field rather than in query string, just a suggestion. – HSharma"*

...

> *@Fred-ii- I don't know how to ping people, but the comment above this one has what ended up solving my problem. Thanks for your help! – jh95"*

*"@HSharma suggestion was what ultimately solved my problem. I added this to my html form `<?php echo' <input type="hidden" name="token" value="'; if (isset($_GET['token'])) { echo $_GET['token']; } echo '" />' ?>` and in my PHP script I added `$token = $_POST ['token'];` and now the token sets properly. Thanks everyone for your help!"*

However and as I stated in comments:

*"Since the length for it most probably surpasses the column's length, you need to increase it by ALTERing the column to be of a higher value in length, one big enough. You then need to clear the values from it and start over; you have no choice."*